# No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package

Tags: android

At last `Android studio` get problem:

```
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.example.NAMEGAME'
```

I want add gif-animation to layout.
My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.NAMEGAME.forma1"
    android:id="@+id/forma1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/forma1gif"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I found thats problem at `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`. Some people recomended change it to `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.NAMEGAME"`
. But it not help.

How i can add gif-animation (or use app) at my android project?

p.s. sorry for my English.

Comment: `res-auto` is correct. You are probably using a too holder version of t he support library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `vector` drawables, you must add a statement to your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

then add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your `layout.xml` file. After that you can use `app:srcCompat` for vector drawables.

[See more details here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

Comment: i do it, 
add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' to some place...

but it's not work ((( example error...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge, so 
instead of `app:srcCompat="@drawable/forma1gif"`
I used `android:src="@drawable/forma1gif"`

Which worked for me